# Finding the missing number in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programming. I saw the challenge about missing numbers on Geeks for Geeks. The solutions offered are quite complex for me. I wonder if my solution is correct because it seems too easy. Thanks!

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7] 

def missing(): 
    for i in range (len(A)): 

        if A[i+1] != A[i] + 1:
            return A[i] + 1

missing()
```

Comment: [Core Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place to ask such a question, I think.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the list is always sorted? Can there be more than one number missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your example but with list comprehension. This will allow you to return a list of all the missing numbers. Keep in mind your sollution only works for gaps == 1.

```
A = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7] 
def missing(A): 
    x = [A[i] + 1 for i in range (len(A)-1) if A[i+1] != A[i] + 1]
    return x

print(missing(A))
```

output

```
[2, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating how to do this through list comprehension!  It is interesting you changed range to len(A)-1

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your code is quite unstable, but it may work.

I would say this is working better

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7] 

def missing():
    for i in range(len(A)): 
        result = 0

        if A[i+1] != A[i] + 1:
            result A[i] + 1

    return result
missing()
```

But also what if 1 is the missing number?

This code below allows 1 to be the missing number

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7] 

def missing():
    if A[0] != 1:
        result = 1
        return result

    for i in range(len(A)): 
        result = 0

        if A[i+1] != A[i] + 1:
            result A[i] + 1

    return result
missing()
```

Comment: @MapsAside Please can you mark whichever post helped you the most by clicking the tick?

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to handle the case for missing 1!

Answer (score 1):

You can just check that each number in the range of numbers from the first element in the list to the last element in the list exists in the list.

**`for` Loop**:

```py
>>> def missing_num(numlist):
        numlist.sort()
        missing = []
        for i in range(numlist[0], numlist[-1]+1):
            if i not in numlist:
                missing.append(i)
        return missing

>>> missing_num([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7])
[6]
```

**List Comprehension**:

```py
>>> def missing_num(numlist):
        numlist.sort()
        nums = list(range(numlist[0], numlist[-1]+1))
        return [i for i in nums if i not in numlist]

>>> missing_num([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7])
[6]
```

---

With some randomized lists:

```py
>>> for _ in range(5):
    randlist = random.sample(list(range(10)), 7)
    print(randlist, missing_num(randlist))

    
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9] [6, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8] [3, 4]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9] [2, 7, 8]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] [3]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8] [1, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing alternative ways of handling this problem. And they are a lot simpler than doing this through totals/sums as offered in solution methods on GfG.